# Sending multiple files in discord Embed - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For now, I have sent files via link (image below), but for security reasons I can't anymore.
[image: File via link]

A first idea that came to me is to send one file at a time in different messages, but I don't like it.

So, there is a way to send multiple files in a Discord embed (Or multiple files in a single message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

This can be accomplished by making a list of `discord.File` objects, then passing it as `Messageable.send(files=your_list_of_files)`.

I've included code below which opens a list of file objects based on their filenames.

### Code

```py
files_to_read: list[str] = []
files_to_send: list[discord.File] = []
for filename in files_to_read:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:  # discord file objects must be opened in binary and read mode
        files_to_send.append(discord.File(f))
await {Messageable}.send(files=files_to_send)
```

### Reference

[`discord.File`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.File)

[`Messageable.send`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.abc.Messageable.send)